# PostgreSQL spread array values as input parameters for using clause

Tags: postgresql

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo(vsql text, vals text[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

    execute vsql using vals;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;


select demo('select $1 || $2', ARRAY['Barrett', ' Gilmour'] );

ERROR:  there is no parameter $2
LINE 1: select $1 || $2
```

The error is that postgres does not understand that the two items in the array must be spread to the input parameters $1 and $2. It understand the entire array as value for $1

Comment: Could you just use `demo('select $1[1] || $1[2]', '{Barrett, Gilmour}')`?

Comment: the idea is that query will be dynamic, I just have control over the arguments I send to it

Comment: Even if the parameter passing would work, your function would result in "Query has no destination for result". And as the function is declared `returns void` you can't return anything to begin with.

Comment: ohhh god, this is only a example to demonstrate the problem. this is not my real function

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in SO question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83278/postgressql-dynamic-execute-with-argument-values-in-array, the EXECUTE ... USING will treat an array as a single parameter.

You could try this hack, which edits the passed SQL statement so that $n becomes $1[n]

```
vsql := regexp_replace( vsql, '[$]([0-9]+)', '$1[\1]', 'g' );
```

The array `vals` is treated as a single parameter but the parameterised select can index into it to get the elements.

a_horse_with_no_name mentioned your other problem which is that your function doesn't actually return anything. If you want to see what is being executed:

```
-- anyelement is a polymorphic pseudo-type
-- problem with returning 'setof record' is that select * from so_demov3() gives error 
--  ERROR: a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"

drop function so_demov3(anyelement, text, text[]);
create function so_demov3(rec_type anyelement, p_sql text, p_vals text[]) returns setof anyelement  as
$$
declare v_sql text;

begin
  -- edit the executable SQL stmt so that $n -> $1[n]
  v_sql := regexp_replace( p_sql, '[$]([0-9]+)', '$1[\1]', 'g' );
  return query execute v_sql using p_vals;
end;
$$
language plpgsql volatile;
```

And call it like this:

```
select * from so_demov3(null::text, 'select $1 || $2', array['Barrett', 'Gilmour'] );
```

Comment: cool, looks like a hack solution to apply in some cases due to this lead to typecast problems to me. because of course not always the query will be such select $1 || $2, it actually is call to functions and inserts updates, upserts...

actually because the way I get the values to the array  ... using avals(hstore(p_record))

avals returns a text[]