# PostgreSQL how to identify if values need to be quoted

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to write a function that will dynamically create the sql statement, but I am facing problems with typecasts so, how can I identify using the type of field if it needs to be quoted

```sql
-- using this I can recover the types of each field
-- but I do not have a simple way to express that for a specific type it need
-- to quote

create table test (
  id serial not null,
  employee_name text,
  salary decimal(12,2),
  hire_date date,
  active boolean
);

select column_name,data_type, null as need_to_be_quoted 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'table_name';
```

```
  column         type          need to be quoted (this is a missing information)
-------------------------------------
  id             integer       false
  employee_name  text          true
  salary         decimal       false
  hire_date      date          true
  active         boolean       false
```

`quote_ident` docs says:

> Return the given string suitably quoted to be used as an identifier in an SQL statement string. Quotes are added only if necessary

But it is not what I was expecting:

```sql
insert into test (employee_name, salary, hire_date, active) 
values (quote_identy('John Doe'), quote_identy(100000), quote_identy(current_date), quote_identy(true));
```

This is kind of necessary because I am trying to generate the statement string dinamically.

I have values to be inserted in some table, I can discover the type of each value, but to generated the insert string statement, I should know if a specific value type should be quoted or not for example

- text: type should be quoted in the string statement
- boolean: should not be quoted
- numeric: should not be quoted
- date: should be quoted

Comment: `quote_ident()` is not for constant values - only for identifiers. You may be looking for `quote_literal()` or `format()` or `execute '...' using ...` but it's unclear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: You should use `quote_ident()` for the _column names` nonetheless to make sure those identifiers are properly quoted

Comment: I have a values to be insert in some table, I can discover the type of each value, but to generated the insert string statement, I should know if a specific value type should be quoted or not for example

text type should be quoted in the string statement
boolean should not be quoted 
numeric should not be quoted
date should be quoted

Comment: Follow the last list in your question, i.e. do not use quotation marks for numeric and Boolean types. Values of all types **can be** quoted, so nothing bad happens when you accidentally use redundant quotes.

Comment: Example - [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=546c7b049a591c620052b1f923f182a0)

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote. Quoting adds complexity and if you don't get it just right it has [syntax and security issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead use bind parameters. The details depend on what database library you're working with, but the basic idea is always the same. First prepare the statement with placeholders for your values. Then execute it passing in the values. The database takes care of putting the values into the statement. You can execute the same prepared statement multiple times optimizing your coding and database calls.

Here's how you'd do it in [PL/pgSQL with EXECUTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). The linked documentation has lots of information about safely executing dynamic queries.

```
do $$
begin
  execute '
    insert into test (employee_name, salary, hire_date, active) 
    values ($1, $2, $3, $4)
  ' using 'John Doe', 100000, current_date, true;
end;
$$;
```

Furthermore, while writing a SQL builder is a good exercise, it's also very complicated and very easy to get subtly wrong. There are plenty of libraries which will build SQL for you.

Here's your statement using PHP's [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries).

```
DB::table('test')->insert([
  'employee_name' => 'John Doe',
  'salary' => 100000,
  'hire_date' => current_date,
  'active' => true
);
```

If you're curious about how SQL builders work, you can dig inside Laravel for ideas. Writing one in PL/pgSQL is ambitious, but I don't know of one that exists. Good luck!

Comment: This is what I am trying to accomplish, but I have to do it using plpgsql

Comment: @HerbertPimentel Sorry, I got it in my head somehow that you're using PHP. I've updated the answer with a PL/pgSQL example.

Comment: Thanks, but all the question is that I need to generate the string statement dinamically just as you do using laravel. and postgres also have a problema to "spread" an array of values to the "using" clause. Check that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278223/postgresql-spread-array-values-as-input-parameters-for-using-clause

Comment: @HerbertPimentel Your idea there has issues because you cant put multiple types, as you have here, into a single array. You could cast them all to text and hope Postgres can cast them back correctly, but that adds complexity and bugs. Instead, consider having your SQL builder only [`prepare`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) the statement, using bind parameters as above, and return the name. Let the user [execute it and pass in their values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html).